# STREAMLIT : ValueError: The feature names should match those that were passed during fit. Feature names must be in the same order as they were in fit

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, streamlit, valueerror

I have a bug with my Streamlit ( I use VS Code to write my code),

I ran several prediction models on my notebook (Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda Navigator),
I downloaded one of them:

**Code on my Notebook**

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

from joblib import dump, load
dump(lr, 'LinearRegression.joblib')
```

After doing this, I imported the sorted DataFrame into my Streamlit, the code for encoding and standardizing my data before launching the model, and finally the model itself.

**Code on my Streamlit**

```
df = pd.read_csv("df_clean.csv", low_memory = False, index_col = 0)
Linear_Regression = load('LinearRegression.joblib') 

# Separation 
target_1 = df["AttendanceTimeSeconds"]
df_att = df.drop(["AttendanceTimeSeconds"], axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_att, target_1, test_size=0.20, random_state = 42)

X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
X_test = X_test.reset_index(drop=True)
y_train = y_train.reset_index(drop=True)
y_test = y_test.reset_index(drop=True)

columns = df_att.columns
num = df_att._get_numeric_data().columns
cat = list(set(columns) - set(num))
num= list(num)

# Standardisation 
sc = StandardScaler()

X_train[num] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[num])
X_test[num] = sc.transform(X_test[num])

# Encoding
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop="first", sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')

X_train_encoded = ohe.fit_transform(X_train[cat])
X_test_encoded = ohe.transform(X_test[cat])

X_train_encoded = pd.DataFrame(data=X_train_encoded, columns=ohe.get_feature_names_out(cat))
X_test_encoded = pd.DataFrame(data=X_test_encoded, columns=ohe.get_feature_names_out(cat))

#Reconstitution of X_train and X_test
X_train = pd.concat ([X_train[num].reset_index(drop=True) , X_train_encoded.reset_index(drop=True)], axis =1)
X_test = pd .concat ([X_test[num].reset_index(drop=True), X_test_encoded.reset_index(drop=True) ], axis =1)

y_pred_lr = Linear_Regression.predict(X_test) # prédictions Linear Regression
```

However, I am getting this error message displayed on my Streamlit page.

[Screenshot of my Streamlit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHCQI.png)

I understand that this is an issue related to my variables, that they do not have the same order between the model and the DataFrame. However, the DataFrame I have used is exactly the same, and the code for splitting, encoding, and standardizing is exactly the same. So I do not understand where this difference in column order is coming from.

I tried another approach, once the splitting, encoding, and standardization were done in my notebook, I downloaded and imported X_train, X_test, y_train, and y_test into my Streamlit code:

[Screenshot of my VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifh8n.png)

But I still get the same error message.

So I went to check the display of the columns in X_train:

**Notebook**

[Screenshot of X_train columns from Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1t1L.png)

**Streamlit**

[Screenshot of X_train columns from Streamlit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmpsd.png)

So indeed, the order of columns is not the same, but how is this possible? The X_train in my Streamlit comes from the notebook. Here is the code I used in my notebook to extract it :

```
X_train.to_csv("X_train.csv")
```

Are there any parameters I should add when downloading the initial DataFrame or the X_train, X_test... DataFrames, or when downloading the model with joblib?

For your information, the DataFrame has a shape of (1295782, 18) before splitting and encoding.
After splitting and encoding:
(1036625, 349)
(259157, 349)
(1036625,)
(259157,)

So it seemed more relevant to use joblib, which handles large amounts of data better.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the features used in training the model will work in the test set, after loading the trained model from the .joblib file, you can extract the features used to train the model (`LR_features` shown below) and compare this to the test dataframe such that they contain the same set.

```
Linear_Regression = load('LinearRegression.joblib') 
LR_features = Linear_Regression.feature_names
```

Next, I'd recommend to skip the Standardization phase and instead you'll want to subset your test dataframe by selecting only columns listed in `LR_features`. This should be able to give you the identical set of columns for the test dataframe and trained model.

Hope this helps.